# Bluetooth devices all disconnect simultaneously, repeating once in a while

Tags: bluetooth, crash

So, it looks like my `bluetoothd` is occasionally crashing with SIGABRT:

[image: screenshot of the Console app on macOS showing a series of bluetoothd crashes within a few minutes of eachother]

Usually, it's a couple times a day; but just now it's happened over and over in the last hour or so.

Here's a full crash log for the most recent one: https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/41bc8f85103ad1eddd5118774db82863

How can I further debug this?

Comment: Try to reset the Bluetooth Module